# How to use a moustache/parameter with a v-on

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to iterate through a set of items and call a function depending on the value of each item.  Example:

```
<div v-for="(cluster, idx) in active_clusters">
  <a href="#/cluster_search" v-on:click="alert({{ idx }})">{{ cluster.title }}</a><br>
</div>
```

It seems like this should be possible but unfortunately the above syntax does not work.

The [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html) at one point says "Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes, instead use a v-bind directive" which hints that this is not the correct path.  None of the `v-on` examples have mustaches either.  Not sure which direction to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use the mustache. The `v-on:click="alert(idx)"` is sufficient.